Validation Error Placement for a list editable field
I have enabled list editable on one of my django admin to allow user update the min and max value. I have set a validation in place to make sure that min is not greater than max. The validation works as expected. However, I am not really happy with the way the message is displayed.
So currently as seeing in the screenshot, the error message appears right above the field which messes up the alignment of the table. The column with error becomes wider than the others and it's not even highlighted with red.

What I am trying to achieve instead is to show the error on the top of the page like
Please correct the errors below.
Min value cannot be greater than max value
....

and simply have the errored field highlighted with red border.
what is the best way to achieve this?
I tried overriding the is_valid function in my CustomModelForm but I can't add the messages there since I don't have access to the request object. Anything I tried to pass the request object was in vain.
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
           
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__' 
        
    def is_valid(self):
        if 'min_quantity' in self._errors:
            # messages.error(self.request, self._errors["min_quantity"])
            print("Handling a specific validation error for 'min'")
            del self._errors['min_quantity']
    
        super().is_valid()

Once I am able to set the django messages, what template should I extend to setup highlighting the errored field?
If not this, how else can I display the error so it's easier on the eyes.
Edit:
MyModel already has a clean function setup that checks for the (min/max) validation. This question is more about displaying the error messages differently in the UI.
